# Show that the eigenvalues of the matrix are symmetric around origin

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, tridiagonal-matrices

> Let $A \in M_n (\mathbb{R})$ be a matrix whose all entries are $0$ except those on the diagonals above and below the principal diagonal, which are all $1$. That is, $a_{ij} = 1$ if $|i-j|=1$ and $0$ otherwise.
> Show that the eigenvalues of the matrix are symmetric around origin

I have to show the eigenvalues of this matrix are symmetric with respect to origin.
If I understand correctly, I'm required to show if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ then so is $-\lambda$. My idea is to somehow show $ \text{Ker}(A+\lambda I)$ is non trivial when I know $ \text{Ker} (A-\lambda I)$ is non trivial, but I'm not being able to deduce this.

Comment: Following your reasoning, you have to show that $Det(A-\lambda I) = 0$ iff $Det(A+\lambda I) = 0$. An hint would be: use $Det(XYZ) = Det(X)Det(Y)Det(Z)$ with suitable $X,Y,Z$

Comment: I'm guessing I would have to write $A+\lambda I$ as a product of 3 matrices, one of which is $A-\lambda I$, right?

Comment: which I am unable to do. Can you help a little more?

Comment: Hint2: $X,Z$ are diagonal matrices

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\lambda$ be an eigenvalue of $A$ corresponding to the eigenvector $v$ of $A$, then $Av=\lambda v$ where
$$v=\begin{bmatrix} x_1\\ x_2\\x_3\\ x_4 \\\dots \\ x_{n-1}\\
x_n\end{bmatrix}.$$

Now take $w=\begin{bmatrix} x_1\\ -x_2\\x_3\\ -x_4 \\\dots \\ x_{n-1}\\
-x_n\end{bmatrix}$.
Then $Aw=-\lambda w$ and thus the proof follows.

Comment: Equivalently, we find that $A$ is similar to $-A$. In particular, we have $-A = DAD^{-1}$, where $D$ is the diagonal matrix
$$
D = \pmatrix{1\\&-1\\&&1\\&&&-1\\&&&&\ddots}
$$